# Почему нельзя вложить блок в блочный элемент

Tags: html, css, css3

Почему нельзя внести `div` внутрь `p`? Если внести `h1` или же `a`, то всё работает.

```css
p {
   width: 300px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px black solid;
   display: block;
}
p div {
   width: 50%;
   height: 100%;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<p><div></div></p>
```

Comment: `h1` внутри `p` вообще-то тоже не работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) указано следующее:

> A p element's end tag may be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul`, element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `a` element.

---

> закрывающий тег элемента *p* может быть опущен если *p* элемент расположен сразу за `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul` элементами, или если больше нет содержимого в родительском элементе или родительский элемент не `a`/

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('p').length);
```

```css
p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: block;
}
p div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <div></div>
</p>
<p>
  <h1></h1>
</p>
```

Comment: А в чём разница с моим ответом?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в ссылке на спецификацию, и другой сниппет :-) ну и цитата немного отличается :)

Comment: Отсутствием скобок)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, не, у меня еще количество `p` выводится - и оно 4 вместо двух, по крайней мере в хроме :)

Answer (score 7):

Потому что спецификация html5 содержит особые правила автозакрытия некоторых тегов. В том числе это относится к тегу `p`. Он закрывается автоматически перед блочными элементами, таблицами и списками. Это позволяет писать подобный код:

```css
body > * {
  color: blue;
}

body > * > * {
  color: red;
}

p {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph
<p>The other one
<ul><li>And the list</ul>
```

Можно заметить, что это правило распространяется только на парсинг - скрипты управляют непосредственно элементами и могут сделать по-другому:

```js
~function () {
  var d = document.createElement("div");
  d.textContent = "789";
  document.querySelector("p").appendChild(d);
}();
```

```css
body > * {
  color: blue;
}

body > * > * {
  color: red;
}

p {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<p>123
<div>456</div>
```

Tag omission (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

> The start tag is required. The end tag may be omitted if the `<p>` element is immediately followed by an `<address>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<blockquote>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<fieldset>`, `<footer>`, `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<hr>`, `<menu>`, `<nav>`, `<ol>`, `<pre>`, `<section>`, `<table>`, `<ul>` or another `<p>` element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element is not an `<a>` element.